# Replace most non alphanumeric characters with one value, remaining with another

Tags: c#, regex

I need to replace all non alphanumeric characters in a string with either dashes, or in the case of single quotes and underscores, nothing at all.  Suggestions on how to do this in C# with the regex class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(input, @"[^a-zA-Z0-9]", m =>(m.Value == "'" || m.Value == "_") ? "" : "-");
```